# I've never... vs 'I've never... myself

Tags: american-english, reflexive-pronouns

Recently I watched video about some English (US) vocabulary(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZOOSIPzi3Ls&t=16m54s) where the guy says that adding 'myself' to the end of the sentence with structure 'I've never' makes it more natural and doesn't change the meaning of the sentence.(E.g 'I've never been to Spain' and 'I've never been to Spain **myself**').

Is it really natural and are there any rules when I can use it?

> I've never thought about it myself.
>   I've never had this feeling myself.
>   I've never read 'Heart of Darkness' myself.
>   I have never traveled by airplane myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply disagree with the video. The use of reflexive pronouns as intensifiers **is certainly** more common in informal English (including speech) because the informal tends to go in for a more dramatic tone than is normal for formal English. But it is still rare even in informal English.

> I myself had breakfast at home this morning. In addition to orange juice and cereal, I had toast and jam myself. And then I myself had a leisurely cup of coffee before I went to meet my girlfriend myself.

does not sound conversational; it merely sounds bizarre. If you start inserting reflexive pronouns into all your sentences, you will sound insane.

A common use of the reflexive pronoun is in setting up a contrast:

> I myself did not serve in the military, but I grew up on an Army base.

It is a tool, used more often in speech than in writing, but a tool that if over used sounds very, very odd.

Comment: I agree with Jeff. If you are asked "Have you ever been to France?" there is no reason to add _myself_ to the answer, because the question was about you. However, if the conversation was about some aspect of French life, you might say "I've never been to France myself, but my sister lived there for a year and she told me…"